# Sailing out of London

Tags: schengen, cruising, 90-180-visa-rules

I'm cruising round trip out of London in July 2019, my ship stops at several EU ports. Do those port days count towards the 90 day limit for the EU zone? I will be in EU before and after cruise so I need this info to calculate my total days.

Comment: It's the *Schengen* zone that has the 90-day limit -- it includes non-EU countries and not all EU countries are party to it.

Comment: You can use this calculator https://ec.europa.eu/assets/home/visa-calculator/calculator.htm?lang=en to work it out

Comment: No specifically stated it so far. If the port is in a country that participates in Schengen, yes, it counts.